# Starjedi TTF font on production server not working

Tags: css, fonts

So as the title says, I have downloaded a custom font named 'Star jedi' (filename is Starjedi.tff).
It works on my local dev machine after I install the font on my machine a:nd I can reference the class in my stylesheet like this :

```
.jedifont {
    font-family: "Star jedi",arial;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px black,10px 10px 10px yellow;
}
```

However, when I install the font on my Production server and use the same code, the text does not style using the class I created above.

I have also tried the following on my production machine:

```
.jedifont {
    font-family: "Star jedi",arial;
    src: url("https://www.mysitename.co.uk/folder/folder/Starjedi.ttf") format('truetype');
    font-size: 40px;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px black,10px 10px 10px yellow;
}
```

and

```
.jedifont {
    font-family: "Star jedi",arial;
    src: url("../fonts/Starjedi.ttf") format('truetype');
    font-size: 40px;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px black,10px 10px 10px yellow;
}
```

and also this in the  section of the index page :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/Starjedi.tff">
```

Not sure what I'm missing folks and would appreciate any pointers!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your css you should declare a `@font-face` before using it, like:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'My Font';
    src: url('path/to/font.ttf');
    /* src for additional formats, as fallback for incompatible browsers */
    src: url( 'path/to/font.woff' ) format( 'woff' ),
         url( 'path/to/font.eot' ) format( 'embedded-opentype' ),
         url( 'path/to/font.ttf' ) format( 'truetype' ),
         url( 'path/to/font.svg' ) format( 'svg' );
}
```

The `@font-face` declaration is where `src` should be. Then you can use the font, like:

```css
element {
   font-family: 'My Font';
}
```

It is recommended using several formats for best support across browsers. And also make sure the path in url('path/to/font') correctly points to the source file. Check for 404 errors in the browser console.